# <pe:keyFilter> tag not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

This is not working in my application. It still accept numbers also.

```
<p:inputText id="Name" value="#{dependbean.name}" maxlength="30">
     <pe:keyFilter mask="alpha"></pe:keyFilter>
</p:inputText>
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the `<pe:keyFilter>` outside of the `<p:inputText>` and use the `for` attribute to point which component is the filter defined for.

```
<p:inputText id="Name" value="#{dependbean.name}" maxlength="30" />
<pe:keyFilter mask="alpha" for="Name" />
```

Comment: Have you tried the [showcase](http://fractalsoft.net/primeext-showcase-mojarra/views/keyFilter.jsf) ? If it doesn't work for you either, then it's some browser issue, IMHO. It works, then I believe you have some configuration problem.

Comment: This clearly means it's some broser issue. What browser are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<p:inputText id="Name" value="#{dependbean.name}" maxlength="30">
     <pe:keyFilter regex="/[ABC]/i"></pe:keyFilter>
</p:inputText>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the you have the element added in the beginning of the file

```
<html ... 
xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">
```

if still doesn't work, make sure the pom.xml file has the dependencies from primefaces extensions.
If not, add this to the pom between  tags:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces.extensions/primefaces-extensions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work with:

```
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
```

And:

```
<p:inputText id="phone" 
...
>
     <p:keyFilter mask="num"/>                                                                                                      
</p:inputText>
```

Try adding `jquery.keyfilter.js` from [here](https://github.com/akzhan/jquery-keyfilter) in your JS folder.

Then add this to your JSF page with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/js/jquery.keyfilter.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why would you need to add the JavaScript? It will be included by simply having the component on your page. See https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/8a6bc2f4ffe68d5f20106c125110997732db9e21/primefaces/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/keyfilter/KeyFilter.java#L32